# AngularJS ui-router abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I recently migrated from ngRoute to ui-router. I have a page that has 2 sections.

Right section displays current item details, 
Left section shows similar items to current item.

Once user clicks a similar item from left list, right section will reload with clicked item id and left section will stay same.

To keep left section still on user item navigations, i defined left section as an abstract state and right section as it's child state. (you cant view similar items if you arent looking to an item).

Left section (listview) is parent and contains a ui-view in HTML to embed item details.

To load similar items on page open, i need to know which item is being loaded by my child state. But i cant define same url for both abstract state and it's child state.
i tried to resolve $stateParams in abstract state with no chance.

my state configuration is below

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('item', {
            //url: '/items/:itemName/:itemID'
            url: '/items',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemListTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemListController as itemList'
        }).state('item.itemDetails', {
            url: '/:itemName/:itemID',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemDetailTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemDetailController as itemDetail'
        });
```

how can i access itemID from my abstract state (from ItemListController)?

Comment: Try changing `item` url to `/items/:itemName/:itemID` and `item.details` to `/details`. To me - more reasonable. `items` should be reserved for `/items` where you display a list and has nothing to do with single view. As abstract state can't be initialised, you won't be able to access `/items` route directly which kinda kills your flow. To load similar items, wrap them in a directive and access `$stateProvider.current` to get params & data to retrieve similar items. Take a look at properties section here -> http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: with all parameters in parent abstract state (item) page will reload on every similar item click. i am trying to keep similar item section same while reloading details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem using angular scope variable. parent contains an ui-view to show child state contents. so child and parent state share same scope therefore i can notify parent about selected item id and parent can update it's view.

parent state has a scope function like this

```
$scope.notifySelectedItem = function(selectedItemID){};
```

and child state can call this function from it's scope

```
$scope.notifySelectedItem($stateParams.itemID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would model this as a single state with two named views.  The subject of your state is a single item and related data, so your state should probably revolve around that.  You have described two views, one which shows the item details, and another which shows other things, but the primary subject is still the one item.

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('item', {
        url: '/item/:itemID',
        views: {
          detail: {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemDetailTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemDetailController as itemDetail'
          }, related: {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemListTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemListController as itemList'
          }
        }           
    });
```

In your parent view, add two named ui-views, where the views defined above will plug into:

```
<div ui-view="related"></div>
<div ui-view="detail"></div>
```

Now, you can enhance this using resolves to preload the data before the controller is invoked:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('item', {
        url: '/item/:itemID',
        resolve: { 
          item: function($http, $stateParams) {
            return $http.get('/item/' + $stateParams.itemID); 
          },
          related: function($http, $stateParams) { 
            return $http.get('/item/' + $stateParams.itemID + "/related");
          },
        },
        views: {
          detail: {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemDetailTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemDetailController as itemDetail'
          }, related: {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/item/ItemListTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ItemListController as itemList'
          }
        }           
    });

app.controller("ItemListController", function($scope, related) { $scope.related = related.data; });
app.controller("ItemDetailController", function($scope, item) { $scope.item = item.data; });
```

Comment: with your solution, page would refresh every time user clicks a similar item, which i am trying to avoid